# how to send a message through socket.io and nestjs for 2 connected users

Tags: socket.io, nestjs

I'm trying to set up a simple chet system between 2 users authenticated by JWT, I try to look for a simple solution but without creating a room, I don't see any other solution. tell me what you think and if you have any areas for improvement, don't hesitate
Back

```
@SubscribeMessage('message')
  async handleEvent(
    @MessageBody() data: any,
    @ConnectedSocket() client: Socket,
  ) {
    const jsonObject = JSON.parse(client.handshake.headers['user'].toString());
    console.log(jsonObject)
    await this.chatService.create(data);
    this.server.emit('message-send', [
     "test",
      data.receiver
    ]);
  }

  afterInit(server: Server) {
    console.log(server);
  }


  async handleConnection(client: Socket, ...args: any[]) {
  const token = client.handshake.auth.token; // Récupérer le token JWT de l'en-tête
  try {
    const decodedToken = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_JWT); 
    client.handshake.headers['user'] = JSON.stringify(decodedToken)
    console.log('User authenticated:', decodedToken.sub);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Unauthorized access:', err.message);
    client.disconnect(true); // Déconnexion du client non authentifié
  }
}
```

FRONT

```
  const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsInVzZXJuYW1lIjoiIiwicm9sZSI6IiIsInV0aWxpdHkiOiJhdXRoIiwiaWF0IjoxNjk2NjAzMjU3LCJleHAiOjE2OTY2MDUwNTd9.dnRtqZBTktYqbPQmz13Rj4F6De-2PQA6-UUvImTF-4E';
      const socket = io('http://localhost:3001',{
        transports: ['websocket'], // Assurez-vous d'utiliser WebSocket comme transport
        auth: { token } // Incluez le token JWT dans l'authentification
      });
      socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('Connected');

        socket.emit('message', { 
          content: "content",
          file_url: "ccc",
          sender: 1,
          receiver: 2

        });
        
      });
      socket.on('message-send', function(data) {
        console.log('message-send', data);
      });
```

I try to look for a simple solution but without creating a room, I don't see any other solution.